# Python POST requests on Facebook “account recovery” and strange output

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing

I wanna make script, which recover my account, so i wanna send my email to input by POST and scrap next page, but my output is strange(or encryption:). My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Soup = BeautifulSoup


#Parse page, i need "lsd_value" to send POST request
x = requests.get('http://m.facebook.com/login/identify?ctx=recover')
x.encoding = "utf-8"
parsed = BeautifulSoup(x.content, "html.parser")
print(parsed)

lsd_value = parsed.find('input', {'name': 'lsd'})
output_lsd_value = lsd_value['value']
print(lsd_value['value'])

#POST 
headers = {
"Host": "m.facebook.com",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0",
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Language": "en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3",
"Accept-Encoding":  "gzip, deflate, br"}
payload={
"lsd": output_lsd_value,
"email": "correct facebook_email",
"did_submit": "Search"
}

#Send and print POST request
session = requests.Session()
x = session.post('http://m.facebook.com/login/identify?ctx=recover', 
headers=headers, data=payload)
print "x.content:", x.content
x.encoding = "utf-8"
parsed = BeautifulSoup(x.content, "html.parser")
print"parsed:", parsed
```

My output:
 No handlers could be found for logger "bs4.dammit"(What is this??)
 parsed: � �oM��������J"n��*k�XS*�*�=Zl���1�T������$�RB��"

�x.�����s'R!��  �����I�I�a�Б�#]CTG�"jo�����su����=8�Cv�n�r����܍�]��fR%���/<)���[2�#)�s���PÌ�8�`lY/�Ks`��&�#q��z�J�JG��M���6�\5��a@ٮx@�_u��[[=�`����  ��1��]$����l4��5z?�7�����bq�5C[�-=vC��]��U��|Af�l5��蝒-�kZ�Zjay�!KCB 
��h����;�J��q��~106�I���m�l�k�xf)�����#���y�}�`;�|��]9�՞TQTC��

Comment: Could it be that Facebook _thought that_ you are trying to steal someone else's password?

Comment: @Selcuk I wanna print account name only, after send POST with e-mail address.